# javascript call is not passing correct value

Tags: php, javascript

I want to pass one tables id to a javascript. its working for the values `1,2,3,...` but the actual value i want to send is `001,002,003,....` But for these values its not working. 
The value showing in console and getting in javascript function are as follows

```
001->1  
002->2  
.  
.  
009->9   
010->8  
011->9   
012->10  
.  
.
```

php code is

```
<td> <a style="text-decoration:none; " href="#" onclick="updateCaste('.$rows['caste_code'].')" ><img src="prjct/edit-icon.png" width="20" height="20"> </a></td>
```

javascript code is

```
function updateCaste(x)
{
        alert(x);
}
```

Plz somebody help me to solve this problem..

Comment: When a number begins with `0` it's treated as octal.

Comment: how can i solve this? :-(

Comment: Are you trying to send numbers or strings?  `1` is a number, `"001"` is a string.

Comment: What kind of value you want to pass integer or string? If it's integer then `1 === 001`. Can  you explain bit more whey you need 001?

Comment: @DeepakBiswal—but `10 !== 010`, see [*ECMA-262 Numeric Literals*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.3) and [*OctalIntegerLiteral*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-B.1.1). ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put quotes around the value so it will be treated as a string, not a number:

```
<td> <a style="text-decoration:none; " href="#" onclick="updateCaste(\''.$rows['caste_code'].'\')" ><img src="prjct/edit-icon.png" width="20" height="20"> </a></td>
```